# conditionally running tests with build flags not working

Tags: testing, go, conditional-compilation, property-based-testing

I'm running some tests in golang and I want to avoid running the slow ones, for example this one uses bcrypt so it's slow:

```
// +build slow
package services

import (
    "testing"
    "testing/quick"
)

// using bcrypt takes too much time, reduce the number of iterations.
var config = &quick.Config{MaxCount: 20}

func TestSignaturesAreSame(t *testing.T) {
    same := func(simple string) bool {
        result, err := Encrypt(simple)
        success := err == nil && ComparePassWithHash(simple, result)
        return success
    }

    if err := quick.Check(same, config); err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
}
```

To avoid running this in every iteration I've set up the `// +build slow` flag. This should only run when doing `go test -tags slow` but unfortunately it's running every time (the -v flag shows it's running).

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: "To distinguish build constraints from package documentation, a series of build constraints must be followed by a blank line." https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/

Comment: I think package testing already has a "short" mode triggered with -short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `// +build slow` needs to be followed by a blank line

To distinguish build constraints from package documentation, a series of build constraints must be followed by a blank line.

visit [Build Constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints)